# How to show comment in Task List View?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a document library (lib). There is an approval workflow (WF) on it. Whenever a new document is added, the WF will start. In the workflow, before a task is assigned, I set values for the task fields TaskName and Comments. DealName and DocumentComment are the fields in the current item which are site columns with the library.

[image]

Now, if I go to the Task list, the title column show the value for TaskName, but I could not figure out how to show the Comments in the view of task list. In the List setting page, I could not find the column related with comments.

[image]

However, if go to task detail page, then we can see the comments:

[image]

is there  a way to show the comment in the view of task list?

Thanks